# C# with PowerBI package: Cannot update RefreshSchedule

Tags: c#, dataset, powerbi

I could get the Dataset from below code:

```
var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_ApiUrl), _tokenCredentials);
var datasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetsAsync(new Guid(_workspaceId));
```

However, there is error when I run below code (datasets.Value.Count > 0):

```
await client.Datasets.UpdateRefreshScheduleAsync(new Guid(_workspaceId), datasets.Value[datasets.Value.Count - 1].Id, refreshSchedule);
```

Exception Error:

> "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"

---

Supplement the API Permissions of PowerBI:
[image]

Comment: Make sure your account has rights to do this, and also the app registration used has rights to do this (`Dataset.ReadWrite.All`).

Comment: Hi @AndreyNikolov, I supplemented API Permissions of PowerBI for your reference. `Dataset.ReadWrite.All` is granted already and Backend is using this PowerBI to access PowerBI resources. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegated account through which the app is running / service principal should be added with full control to the dataset in addition to  the app has permission at the Azure AD end.

Also, you can capture the server response to understand more on the error.

The Server response will have additional information on why the Service returned a Forbidden

Attached a sample output below :

[image]

The server response will be helping you more - especially the header with PowerBI error Info

Comment: Thanks @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT. After I granted privilege to ServicePrincipal in PowerBI console and using your suggested method ScheduleNotifyOption.NoNotification, it is okay to update RefreshSchedule now.

Comment: @DaiKeung, glad to know :)